# Updating an input text field to in turn update a text on Primefaces editor

Tags: javascript, java, html, primefaces

[image]Hello everyone,
I have a small issue regarding updating an email's regards full name in a p:editor from an input text field. I want to be able to change the text from the regard's text area after updating my primefaces input text field with id email_sender.

For instance I have tried these methods which do not work:

**my dialog box containing the input text field and editor**

```
                    <p:dialog header="Share Document via Email" widgetVar="newMailDlg"
                        modal="true" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" height="800"
                        width="100%" id="newMailDlg">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><h:outputText
                                        value="#{msg['email.sender']}:" /></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control input-sm"
                                        id="email_sender"
                                        value="#{EnquiryComponent.senderName}" maxlength="50"
                                        required="false" label="sender">
                                        
                                        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{EnquiryComponent.setRegards()}" 
                                         update="@([id$=email_content])" />
                                    


                                    </h:inputText>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><h:outputText
                                        value="#{msg['email.content']}:" /></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <p:editor id="email_content" widgetVar="email"
                                        value="#{EnquiryComponent.blankEmail.content}" height="250" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:commandButton id="sendEmail" styleClass="green-btn"
                                    ajax="false" value="Send Mail"
                                    action="#{EnquiryComponent.saveEmail(EnquiryComponent.blankEmail, EnquiryComponent.task, true)}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </p:dialog>
```

**My backing bean to update the map containing the key variable in my email template**

```
    public void setRegards() {
        logger.info("Changed recipient name to : " + senderName);
        emailModel.put("user", senderName);
    
        
    }
```

**Bean Setting the P:editor contents**

```
public void onSendMail(String refNo, TreeNode treeNode) {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SIL-mail", Locale.getDefault());
        String sender = rb.getString("mail.default.from");
        blankEmail = new Email();
        task = null;
        blankEmail.setSender(sender);
        
        senderName= SilUtils.getUserObj().getFullUserName();
        
        listGlbAccessUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        listGlbAccessUsers=glbAccessUsersService.getDao().findAll();

        AlfDocument doc = (AlfDocument) treeNode.getData();
        // String link = previewDocument(doc);
        String link = generateAlfrescoEditURL(treeNode);
        link = link.split("&")[0];

        emailModel = new HashMap<>();
        emailModel.put("documentLink", link);
        emailModel.put("refNo", refNo);
        emailModel.put("task", "");
        emailModel.put("user", senderName);

        blankEmail.setContent(mailService.getMailContent("mail_acknowledge.vm", emailModel));

        SilUtils.showDialog("newMailDlg");
    }
```

Comment: You might be better off trying to do it with JavaScript and just updating the p:editor contents with JS code in `onchange` of your input text.

Comment: @Melloware Thanks for the input mate. Can you help me out with writing the JS part? I have not done much JS. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't have that much time to dedicate but this is good learning opportunity for you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a command button with ajax.
Try this :

```
  <p:commandButton id="sendEmail" styleClass="green-btn"
                                process="@this" value="Send Mail"
                                action="#{EnquiryComponent.saveEmail(EnquiryComponent.blankEmail, EnquiryComponent.task, true)}" update="email_content" />
```

If you click the button, now it can update the email_content.

Enjoy, Riccardo.